Error when running python script (from django project) from jenkins
I've done a script that add data from mantis ticket to my django table.
When i execute it  directly on the machine, it work well.
But now i want to make it launch periodically from jenkins so i try to make a wrapper sh :
#!/bin/bash
export PYTHONPATH=/lib/python3.9/
python3.9 <full_script_path>/import_mantis.py

Then i try to execute the sh from jenkins job and i got this error :
Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DEV_Update_Suivi_Installation
[DEV_Update_Suivi_Installation] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins13327687472776211165.sh
+ sh /opt/livraison/jenkins_wrapper/wrapper_import_mantis.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<path>/import_mantis.py", line 4, in    <module>
import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

i think that i havent write the right things but i dont understand where the error is coming from.
I wrote the question there and i'm still searching solution.
Thanks in advance

Is your python environment set up correctly? E.g. have you installed your dependencies within a virtualenv or something like that?

Hi ! No i  installed it directly on the linux machine, i havent set up a virtualenv

The par ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django' tells me that your python interpreter doesnt know django, so if you dont care you can just python3.9 -m pip install django but I would recommend keeping your build agent free from direct dependencies. (Imagine you have a second project that should be built, but needs a different django version)

but django is installed for my python3.9 , because when i execute directly the script it work. is there something to indicate to jenkins with python to use ?
